# Energising Electrostatic Charge Into Nylon Ribbons? Is it possible?

Tags: discharge, charge, electrostatic

Forgive me for how high level this is but this is the goal I'm trying to achieve here:

I want to build a device that has dangling ribbons of a material (lets say nylon for now) that can be actuated to turn electrostatic attraction on and off. The idea here is that these ribbons will be collecting floating pollen in the air using the electrostatic, and later released by turning the electrostatic off. The device would resemble something of a wind chime, just nylon ribbons instead of pipes.

My question is then: how (if at all possible) do I apply and then remove electrostatic charge from a collection of ribbons?

EDIT: This will be an aerial project (from a drone) using an onboard 12 V distribution board from a 3 cell 75 C lipo battery.

Comment: Just wondering, but why do you think pollen will be attracted by an electrostatic charge?

Comment: @Transistor I'd assume that the plastic duster method of collecting dust would be caused by static charge?

Comment: @Transistor I recall reading in some places that bee's use a small amount of electrostatic charge to pull pollen, as well as winds even. This is just mostly where the idea came from. Also, from middle school the experiment where hair gets attracted to a balloon after rubbing it on the wall? Surely pollen is lighter than human hairs, so maybe there's a chance here.

Answer (score 1):

Won't work with Nylon: you need a conductor to be able to move/remove charges from it.

But, that's actually commonly done: in powder coating (to protect metal surfaces), you connect the conducting piece you want to coat to a high voltage source. The other end, you'd bring to about earth potential.

As soon as you don't need the attractive force anymore, you'd disable the high-voltage source and discharge your conductive objects to earth.

Note that your ribbons don't need to be good conductors, just so-and-so conductors; so any fabric that has undergone some metallization or contains carbon fibers or wiring will do.

The real problem is: your pollen *isn't* deterministically charged. That way, it'll be hard to attract it to the conductive surfaces. In powder coating, this is solved by the "gun" that sprays the powder being oppositely charged to the target.

Comment: Interesting point about the pollen not being deterministically charged, but could it be safe to say that if there's a likelihood of attracting ~50% of the pollen?

Also I'm going to update my main question in a section, but this is being done from a drone (aerial, no earth ground) with only a 12 V three cell battery on board. Is this still feasible given that information?

Comment: you need high voltage, no matter what you do to begin with. The question of *how* to generate that from 12 V should be (with as much about your application as possible) be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

[Electrostatic dust collectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_precipitator) work because they have two different kinds of electrode: One is a flat plate, while the other is an array of fine wires. A high voltage is applied between them, with the wires being negative.

The electric field around the fine wires is concentrated enough to ionize the air in their immediate vicinity — this is called corona discharge. Any particles passing through this region will receive a charge. As a result, they get repelled by the wire, and also by each other.

When they leave the area of corona discharge, they retain their charge, and they are also attracted to the other electrode (the flat plate), where they can lose their charge (to some extent) when they touch it. But in general, they retain enough charge to "stick" to the plate.

After some period of operation, it is relatively easy to collect the dust (pollen) from the plate.